# How to initialize row datatype variables?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to create a function that initialize and return the row datatype of a table as

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_default_table_row_object() 
RETURNS mytable AS $$
    DECLARE 
    row mytable;
    BEGIN
        row.field1 := 0;
        row.field2 := -1;
        row.record_reg_id := 1;
        row.record_upd_id := 1;
        row.record_reg_date := current_timestamp;
        row.record_upd_date := current_timestamp;

        RETURN row;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

becuase my table has alot of columns and I need to create dozens of variables at several functions. I would like to use above function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_function() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE    
    i_obj1 mytable := get_default_table_row_object(); -- declare and initialize default values
BEGIN
    -- function body
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this give me the error `ERROR:  default value for row or record variable is not supported`. Has someway to figure it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in the body instead, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_function() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE    
    i_obj1 mytable; -- declare only
BEGIN
    i_obj1 := get_default_table_row_object(); -- set default values
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```